# Declaring and accessing global objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

The well known method for this is to declare `int globalVar = 0` and then -where to use it- `extern int globalVar;` but that didn't work with me for objects from user defined class!

This is an example of what I did:

file1.cpp:

```
 #include "file2.h"  
class list { ....};  
 list * x ;       
//do something with x`
```

file2.cpp:

```
class list;  
 extern list * x;  
//do something with x
```

and this is the error I get:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'list'
```

if I remove `class list`

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' // in `extern list *x;`  
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support 
             default-int
```

thanks for answers , now it's like this :

```
#ifndef _ERRLIST_H_
#define _ERRLIST_H_
#include <queue>
#include <string>

struct errorStruct{
            int errLineNum;
            int errColNum ;
            char * errMessage;
    };
queue <errorStruct> errQueue; //error points here
class ErrList
{

public:
void pushError(int line,int col,char * message);
void popError();    
void printErrors();
int getSize();

};
#endif
```

but I get this error :

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

Comment: The declaration does work, it is the "do something with x" that doesn't work when the compiler isn't told what x is. It does work with `int` because the compiler knows that type already.

Comment: @Bo Persson: That explains the real cause with proper and simplistic wordings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

It's "std::queue<errorStruct>", not "queue<errorStruct>".

Comment: sorry to bother , but I got myself in more trouble ^^' please check http://stackoverflow.com/q/6020559/559465 .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`extern` should be used in the header file. Putting `extern list *x` in the header file is actually an announcement to all source files that there exists a global variable `x` and it is declared somewhere else. If you don't follow this approach, and write `extern list *x` in source file instead (as @Als's did), then you're actually hiding the announcement, and not making it clear to all source files that the global variable `x` exists. Then what might happen? It might happen that you later create another source file `file3.cpp`, in which you might mistakenly declare a global variable with name `x`, which would cause linker error.

So the solution is to make a clear announcement and the correct place of announcement is header file - as that is where all other announcements are made.

Thus, your code should look like this:

- list.h:

  ```
  class list { ....};  
  extern list * x;//extern means the variable declaration is elsewhere
  ```
- list.cpp:

  ```
  #include "list.h"

  list * x;   //alright, the variable declaration is here!

  //use x
  ```
- file1.cpp

  ```
  #include "list.h"

  //use x - no need to write : extern list *x
  ```
- file2.cpp

  ```
  #include "list.h"

  //use x  - no need to write : extern list *x
  ```

---

As for the error related to `queue`, you should qualify it with the namespace `std` in which its defined. Write this:

```
   std::queue <errorStruct> errQueue; 
 //^^^^^ mention the namespace
```

Similarly, if you use `string` (for which you've included the header file), then write `std::string`.

Comment: In `list.cpp`, both an extern variable(`extern list * x ;`) and a global variable (`list * x;`) exist. Don't you think that cause multiple declaration error?

Comment: @Mahesh: No. `extern` doesn't cause any problem. You can use extern even multiple times in a single file. See this : http://www.ideone.com/VPylY

Comment: @Nawaz - One statement tries to declare a new variable(`x`) in the current compilation unit while the other says it(`x`) is declared some where else. How could both exist in a single compilation unit? How could the compiler differentiate between the two ?

Comment: @Mahesh: Multiple `extern` declaration can peacefully coexist in a  single compilation unit, because `extern` itself doesn't declare a new variable. No matter how many times you write `extern list *x`, there will be only one variable declaration.

Comment: @Nawaz - Ok, but how to differentiate between the two when using. Because both share the same name is what confusing me ;)

Comment: @Mahesh: those are NOT two different variables. they are the very same variable. `extern` itself does NOT declare *new* variable.

Comment: @Nawaz - I understand that. But `extern` brings the else where declared variable to the current scope. What if there is a clash with a global variable that shares the same name, which is what happening here.

Comment: @Mahesh: By writing `extern list *x`, you're telling the compiler that *"Ms. Compiler, there variable declaration is elsewhere, please have patience you will find it"*. When you write it again `extern list *x`, you're telling the compiler that *"Ms. Compiler, I told you earlier the variable declaration is elsewhere, pleaseeeeeeee have patience, you will soon find it"*

Comment: @Mahesh: `extern` doesn't "bring" the variable declaration to the current scope; its already in the scope; the compiler just yet to see it. Or if it already have seen it, the `extern` then tells the compiler to use the declaration it already have seen.

Comment: @Nawaz - But while using it, which will have the preference? In this case it is global variable.http://ideone.com/WwAvK. Can I conclude that global variables bearing the same name will have preference over extern variable ?

Comment: @Mahesh: What do you mean by "preference"? extern doesn't declare a new variable. it does **not** declare a variable AT ALL. It simply tells the compiler to look for **the** declaration of `x` IF the program somewhere uses it. See this : http://ideone.com/fxqaF .... now try to understand the error.. and then also see this : http://ideone.com/I5xwO

Comment: @Nawaz - Well, you get the reference error because there is no other file that has a variable `x` declared global. Had if there existed a source file that declared `int x;` as global and initialized, and in the other compilation unit while declared it as `extern` you can ask the value it has. Infact, the example you showed is a single source file.

Comment: @Mahesh: Also. the word "preference" implies that the compiler has two variables which is wrong. Compiler doesn't have option to "prefer" one over another. There is nothing "another".

Comment: @Nawaz - Let me myself create a project in my XCode and check it. BRB

Comment: @Nawaz - `ld: duplicate symbol _x in temp.o and main.o`. This is what I was speaking of. Linker can see both the symbols in the current compilation unit. The one with `extern` while the other is `global` declaration and confuses between the two as to which one use because both share the same name and scope.

Comment: @Nawaz - To sum up, you cheated the compiler and the linker is taking it's revenge on compiler's behalf :)

Comment: @Mahesh: You must have "declared" two variables with same name!

Comment: @Nawaz - That is what the discussion starting point, if I am not wrong. In `list.cpp`, you have both `extern list * x;` and `list * x;`. And how to differentiate between the two in the current source file, `list.cpp`

Comment: @Mahesh: God how many times should I repeat that `extern list *x` does not not not not not not not not declare a variable at all. And in your project, you must have declared a variable in  `temp.h/cpp` and another with same name in `main.cpp`.

Comment: @Mahesh: That is what I am saying. You have declared the variable TWO TIMES. Where in my code do you same two declarations?

Comment: @Nawaz - Got a bit confused. Thanks. Had if you had done what @Als did, it would have been easy to understand. Once again thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh: BTW, the problem you're talking about, has nothing to do with `extern`.  Just try compiling this code with `>> g++ 1.cpp 2.cpp` : http://ideone.com/7OI19 ... you will see the redefinition problem!

Comment: @Mahesh: Also. @Als solution has one problem: if I were to write another source file, the header would not say if there is a global variable declared with name `x` which I can use in `file3.cpp`. But my approach conveys this message nicely, as anyone who is  going to use `list` have to include `list.h` wherein `extern list *x` says that there is a variable declaration elsewhere and you can use it...[contd].

Comment: @Nawaz - Ok. Honestly I still think that you code is confusing because the code has just advantage of not declaring the extern again and again in every source file wishing to use the global object else where declared. If the `extern` goes in the beginning of the source file, then it is easy to think that it is declared else where. At least, I practice the way what @Als used when I am forced to use global variables. I am just seeing your comment. Let me read it first.

Comment: [contd]... Also, in his approach, the declaration is hidden in `file2.cpp`, I might declare another variable with same name `x` in my `file3.cpp`,  assuming that none else have declared this variable before, after all the header says nothing!

Comment: @Mahesh: Who says you cannot write  `extern list *x` in every file? You can. I just said you don't need to.

Comment: @Mahesh: Also. if you practice @Als's approach, you will soon face problem. His approach does not announce that there is global variable declaration.

Comment: @Nawaz - Thanks to the God @Nawaz preaches for making me understand the pitfall finally :P

Comment: @Mahesh: hehe... btw did you clearly understand the problem with @Als's approach?

Comment: @Mahesh: haha... shabash :P... btw what do you do? lets come to yahoo!

Answer (score 1):

Your `file2.cpp` should include header which has definition of `class list`.

***myList.h***

```
class list { ....};
```

***file1.cpp***

```
#include "myList.h"
list * x ;
```

***file2.cpp***

```
#include "myList.h"
extern list * x;
```

Answer (score 0):

As with any class, the complier needs to see its definition before using it. Put the definition of list in a header and include it in the class which uses the list. This is nothing to do with global objects.