# linking error2005 visual studio 2008 c++

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I had struct errorStruct & a queue errQueue definition in yacc.y , then moved it to separate .h file
but it gives me linking error that the definition is found in both yacc.obj and node.obj !!
tried creating new solution but still gives the same error

```
Error   9   error LNK2005: "class std::queue<struct errorStruct,class std::deque<struct          

errorStruct,class std::allocator<struct errorStruct> > > errQueue" (?errQueue@@3V?$queue@UerrorStruct@@V?

$deque@UerrorStruct@@V?$allocator@UerrorStruct@@@std@@@std@@@std@@A) already defined in Node.obj    yacc.obj
```

#### update

first :
Node.h // for node class
yacc.y // rules + errorStruct + queue errQueue + class ErrList : includes "Node.h" & < queue>

then:

Node.h // for node class + errorStruct + queue errQueue + class ErrList : includes < queue>
yacc.y // rules : includes "Node.h"

#### update

in Node.h

```
struct errorStruct{
            int errLineNum;
            int errColNum ;
            char * errMessage;
    };

class ErrList{

public:
void pushError(int line,int col,char * message);
void popError();    
void printErrors();
int getSize();

private :
queue <errorStruct> errQueue;

};
externErrList * se = new ErrList ();
```

the rest of Node.h has nothing to do with this class
in yacc.y just using
`se->pushError(...);`
and as no declaration of class ErrList or errQueue

Comment: A suggestion: SO has a very helpful community but you need to help the community help you by posting all the relevant information in form of a minimalistic code example. Doing so most of the times you will realise what the mistake is and learn a lot from it, if not it helps peeps here to help you better. Posting inadequate information makes the Q go in a loop of asking for more info and just delays the entire process, which is not good for you as well as for us.

Comment: yup , I'm still learning I'll try to do better .. thanks

Comment: *Don't be vague, be an [ace](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints); write a [proper](http://sscce.org/) [test-case!](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml)*

Comment: Can I add this page too? ;) http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should organize the code as:

```
yacc.h   //-----> should have declaration of errQueue & errorStruct

yacc.cc  //-----> should include yacc.h, 
//It can create variables of type errQueue & errorStruct

node.cc  //-----> should include yacc.h
//It can create variables of type errQueue & errorStruct
```

Note that the declarations should only be present in `yacc.h` and it should be included in all your cc files which need to create instances of the said types, If the structures are declared in any of your cc file in addition to the header(yacc.h) then you will end up getting the redefinition errors you mentiones.

Comment: no actually , it goes exactly the opposite way :I have the declaration in Node.h and  yacc.y includes node.h .. I can't control yacc.cpp cuz I use bison to deal with it

Comment: @Katia: could you post the organization of your source code just as i mentioned in my answer? It will help understand your problem better.

Comment: @Katia: Need to see how you have declared your variables, especially `errQueue`, Can you show us parts of code where you have used `errQueue`?

Comment: in Node.h 
struct errorStruct{..... };
queue <errorStruct> errQueue;
including <queue > and using namespace std;

Answer (score 0):

opss! I forgot to post the answer .. sorry ..

got it with the help of @Peter K.'s reference  :

go to VS : project ->  property page -> configuration properties -> linker ->command line

and add `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` in additional options box

Comment: Forcing the linking process is not the solution. You need to reorganize your source so that you do not have the error instead.

Comment: @wilx I know it's just ignoring the error not solving it , but at least I can keep working while I figure out how to solve it. freezing the whole project is not good as well .. don't u think?

Comment: I disagree. You are doing it wrong. Solve it now. If you do not understand the problem now, how do you know you will not introduce more of the same during the time you are ignoring it? ODR is one of the fundamentals of C++.